# javascript vs server event conundrum- iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, asp.net

Ok here is my problem, I've inherited an old ASP.NET 2 website which I've been asked to make iOS capable. My biggest headache so far is that because of the way you have to log into the system right now I need to pass the UserName to the iphone and also run the server Click event. I can do one or the other but not both, and hooking up to the username textbox via either the KeyUp event or the OnChanged event causes other problems with the Objective-C code for the iPhone.

Is there anyway that I can update both the phone and the server at basically the same time?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry I was rather tired and frustrated when I wrote this. Basically I am using the OnClientClick event on an ASP.NET button to fire off some javascript which does a window.location to a custom URL for passing in data to an iphone. Well this works if I return false from the javascript but it also kills the OnClick event which I need to fire off next to login the user to the web app. I have tried multiple different ways to do this is there a standard way that I am just missing.